# provide automatically updates to pro plugins in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to implement WordPress pro plugin automatically updates features.

my plugin is the pro so it not available in WordPress plugins directory.
I found some solution but when I provide updates features to the user at that time WordPress provides view version information link and open up one model with plugin updates detail but also contain Install plugin button.

I don't want that button to display when WordPress open model for plugin updates information.

please help me I have spent too much time on Google and not found any proper solution for that.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.